# outerWidth and outerHeight Change Results on Orientation Change

Tags: javascript, screen-orientation

I'm experiencing a strange result while using `window.outerWidth` and `window.outerHeight`. I'm simply printing out the resolution of a tablet onto a webpage so I can see the dimensions I have to target with media queries.

When I load the webpage in portrait, I get `360x559`. When in landscape I expect to get `559x360` but instead get `640x279`.

I suspect this is because of the navigation bar in the `Chrome` app, but I can't confirm that.

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
<span id="res"></span>
...
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#res").text(window.outerWidth + "x" + window.outerHeight);
    });
</script>
```

I only have one meta tag:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

This was tested on Chrome on multiple Android devices with the same issue.

Can someone explain why the results at first blush seem so janky?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it. Can you post all your meta tags as well?

Comment: What's even more weird is the device emulator Chrome provides works fine. The devices I'm testing on are older and don't have the newest versions of Android so I'm wondering if that may have something to do with it.

Comment: Does that code run during `orientationchange` event? If yea, I assume it's getting the `outerHeight` and `outerWidth` when the orientation hasn't fully updated. I can reproduce the same thing, and fix it by using timeout..

Comment: Nope. It just runs when the page loads. If I want to test on the orientation change, I just refresh the page. It *could* be the page hasn't fully loaded, but the code is wrapped in a `.ready()` shorthand. Let me put it in a 5-second timeout just to see what happens. :)

Comment: Same result. Super weird. I'll leave this question open in case *someone* can reproduce the issue. I find it odd that you can't.